# How can I show the list of quizzes that the user did not participate in them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am developing a web-based training management system that provides the employees with weekly short quizzes. In profile section in the webiste, the employee should be able to see a list of the quizzes that he did not participate in them. I could be able to let the system to show them but not after improving the system, it doesn't show.

First of all, I have the following database design:

```
Quiz Table: QuizID, Title, Description, IsSent
UserQuiz Table: ID, QuizID, Score, DateTimeComplete, Username
```

***IsSent is a flag that refers to the quizzes that have been sent or not***

I put IsSent in the Quiz table because I want the Admin to be able to insert around 50 quizzes in a day. Then, the system will deal with sending them on a weekly basis. Now, when the user wants to see his profile and see the quizzes that he did not participate in them, he should see the the list of quizzes that have been sent and he did not participate in them.

The problem that I am facing it right now is that the system shows the quizzes that have not been sent as a list of quizzes that the employee did not participate in them and this is wrong. **So how I can fix this problem?**

My Query:

```
SELECT     Title, Description
FROM         dbo.Quiz
WHERE     (NOT EXISTS
                          (SELECT     QuizID
                            FROM          dbo.UserQuiz
                            WHERE      (dbo.Quiz.QuizID = QuizID) AND (Username = @Username)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add folllowing line in the end of the query

```
AND IsSent = 1
```

P.S. i'm assuming ur `isSent` column is tinyint and 1 = true

Comment: by doing this, it will show the quizzes stored in the database and they have not been sent to the users and this is wrong. It should only show the quizzes that have been sent to the user and he did not participate in them.

Comment: how we know about those quiz which are sent to the users and users did not participate in it ?

Comment: @TechnologyLover User Quiz stores those question id's which user took ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand properly then you are looking for this query

```
select QuizID, Title, Description, from quiz 
INNER JOIN userquiz ON quiz.QuizID= userquiz.QuizID
where quiz.issent = 1
```